# Is there a special name for functors of form $F : C \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$?

Tags: category-theory

Functors of form $F : C^{op} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ are called [presheaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presheaf_(category_theory)). It seems odd to me that these would be targeted out as opposed functors of form $F: C \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$.

**Question:** Are there special names for functors of form $F: C \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$? If not, why not?

Comment: Perhaps it is simply "precosheaf".

Comment: If $F$ is faithful it could potentially be called a "concretization".

Comment: @C.Dubussy I never saw precosheaf, but I saw copresheaf several times. I guess they both works, as well as (Set-valued)-functor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are seemingly occasionally called [copresheaves](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copresheaf) ([see also](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/space+and+quantity)). They are also themselves presheaves on $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ and it's not uncommon to take such a perspective usually by giving the opposite category its own name.  For example, the category of [affine schemes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/affine+scheme) is equivalent to the opposite category of commutative rings, [scheme](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/scheme#as_sheaves_on_) is a (pre)sheaf on the category of affine schemes, which is to say, functor $\mathbf{CRing}\to\mathbf{Set}$.  A similar thing happens with [locales and frames](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locale#definitions).